# Lists getting deleted in Python

Tags: python, list

I am using Python 3.6
I have a list:

```
listA = [1,2,3,1,2,4]
```

I am trying to remove the repetitive items from the list, so the final list will be

```
listA = [3,4]
```

After I loop once and remove 1s from the list using pop, my loop automatically advances to 3, instead of 2.
To avoid this, I used following logic:

```
ListB= ListA
ListA.clear()
ListA = ListB
```

but once I clear ListA, the other list ListB is also getting cleared automatically. How can I avoid this or solve this issue?

Comment: Make a copy: `ListB = ListA.copy()` or `ListB = list(ListA)` or `ListB = ListA[:]`. Otherwise `ListB` and `ListA` refer to the same object.

Comment: `ListA` isn't the list, it is a *name* for the list. `ListB = ListA` means `ListB` is another name for the same list.

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Python are stored by reference,which means you didn't assign the value of `ListA` to `ListB`, but a pointer to the object.You can use `is` operator to test if two objects have the same address in memory.

Sequences can be copied by slicing so you can use this to copy a list:

```
b = a[:]
```

Also you can use

`b = list(a)`

Or you can use `copy()` module:

```
from copy import copy
b = copy(a)
```

See more details from [How do I copy an object in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

Names of lists in python are actually just references so your new list is a reference to the same list. To actually make a new list you can use

```
ListB = list(ListA)
```

Comment: *Names* in python are actually just references.

Comment: @PeterWood fair enough. I mean the default behavior of lists, as that is not how, say, tuples would work. Fixed.

Comment: How would tuples work?

Comment: `TupleA=(1,2,3,4)
TupleB=TupleA
TupleA=None
TupleA=TupleB
print(TupleA)`
prints `(1,2,3,4)`

Comment: In what way is that different with lists?